# SSIS Package - Get one column from multiple source files

Tags: ssis

I am trying to create an SSIS package that can accept multiple (known) file structures that are dumped into the same processing folder. I am trying to pull the `AccountId` from each file.

The problem I am running into is that my *Data Flow Task* only works for the one specific file that I setup for the *Flat File Source*. In my *Flat File Source* I only make the AccountId column available, but that doesn't appear to resolve the issue.

***Current SSIS Package Structure***

*Foreach Loop:* Loops though all files in the specificed folder

[image: Foreach Loop]

*Data Flow Task:* Processes each file and stores in SQL table

[image: Dataflow Task]

***Example CSV File Structures***

**File 1:**

```
Name | AccountId | Address | City | State
John | 154235    | 1234    | LA   | CA
```

**File 2:**

```
Name | Address | City | State | AccountId | Phone
Kyle | 5825    | Test | KY    | 534534    | 555-555-5555
```

**File :**

```
Name | Address | City | State | Email      | AccountId | Phone
Bob  | 52345   | Fake | WY    | t@test.com | 756313    | 444-444-4444
```

Comment: Is the problem that you want to import from multiple sources simultaneously, or do you want to use the same source to handle multiple file formats?

Comment: I want to import from multiple sources into a table just containing the `AccountId` field. I am getting the sources from different third parties that all dump their files into the same folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The flat file source is going to use the position of the column defined in the connection manager.  It won't try to pull the positions from the headers of each file individually.

If you want to create one source that can handle different locations for a column, then you can either purchase a component that can handle this scenario, or write your own with the script component.

Below is a sample of a Script Component set as an output that should do the job.  You'll have to figure out the parsing of the file on your own, but that shouldn't be so hard.  Just don't forget to configure a variable for the file path, and add AccountId as an output in the *Inputs and Outputs* section.

```cs
public override void CreateNewOutputRows()
{
    int colIdx = -1;
    var text = File.ReadAllText(Variables.FilePath); // Set in Script/ReadOnlyVariables
    var rows = ParseText(text);
    var firstRow = rows.FirstOrDefault().ToList();
    // find matching row
    for (var i = 0; i < firstRow.Count; i++)
    {
        if (firstRow[i] == "AccountId")
        {
            colIdx = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    foreach (var row in rows.Skip(1))
    {
        Output0Buffer.AddRow();
        Output0Buffer.AccountId = row.Skip(colIdx).First(); // configure columns in output
    }
}

public IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> ParseText(string text)
{
    /** implement yourself.  You can find examples online **/
}
```